# How to upload image ,text and video using PHP file in MySql Database from android

Tags: android, json

Can anyone help me ***how to upload images,text and video*** to the database using login webservice with user_id and upload to the MySql Database 
 Here is My code accordingly.
**PHP FILE**:

```
<?php
require '../db_connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['message']))
{
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
    //$user_id=1;
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts(user_id,post_description,is_active,created_at) values('".$user_id."','".$message."',1,'".$date."')");

    if($query){
         $i_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
         if(isset($_POST['img_file'])){
             $sourcePath = $_POST['img_file'];
             // create dir if not exists
            if(!is_dir('../img/Post')){
                 mkdir('../img/Post',0777,true);
            }
            $s_file_name = time()."_".$_POST['img_file'];
            $targetPath = "../img/Post/".$s_file_name;
            if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
                function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
                    $info = getimagesize($source);
                    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
                        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
                        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

                    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
                    return $destination;
                }
                $source_img = $targetPath;

                if(!is_dir('../img/Post/compress')){
                    mkdir('../img/Post/compress');
                }
                $destination_img = '../img/Post/compress/'.$s_file_name;

                $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 50);

                $i_file_type = 1; // 1 for image.
                $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO post_files(post_id,file_name,file_type,is_active) values('".$i_post_id."','".$s_file_name."',$i_file_type,1)");

            }
        }
        if(isset($_POST['video_file'])){
                //echo "in";
            $sourcePath = $_POST['video_file'];
             // create dir if not exists
            if(!is_dir('../img/Post')){
                 mkdir('../img/Post',0777,true);
            }

            $s_file_name = time()."_".pathinfo($_POST['video_file'], PATHINFO_FILENAME).".mp4";
            $s_file_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $s_file_name);
            $targetPath = "../img/Post/convert/".$s_file_name; 
             if(!is_dir('../img/Post/convert')){
                 mkdir('../img/Post/convert',0777,true);
             }
            $s_post_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';

             $handbrake = "HandBrake/HandBrakeCLI";
             $cmd = $s_post_path.$handbrake." -i ".$sourcePath." -o ".$s_post_path.$targetPath." -e x264 -q 25 -r 15 -B 64 -X 480 -O";
                passthru($cmd,$err);

                    $i_file_type = 2; // 2 for video.
                    $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO post_files(post_id,file_name,file_type,is_active) values('".$i_post_id."','".$s_file_name."',$i_file_type,1)");
        }
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Post successfully added.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

**ANDROID CODE:**

```
public class Posts_DATA extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = Posts_DATA.class.getSimpleName();

    EmojiconEditText emojiconEditText;
    EmojiconTextView textView;
    ImageView emojiImageView;
    ImageView submitButton;
    View rootView;
    EmojIconActions emojIcon;

    private TextView buttonChoose;
    private TextView buttonUpload;

    private ImageView imageView;

    private EditText editTextName;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private String UPLOAD_URL = "http://app-1494216827.000webhostapp.com/register_sample/images/upload.php";


    private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private String KEY_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.posts_data);
        rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
        emojiImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emoji_btn);
        submitButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
        emojiconEditText = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.emojicon_edit_text);
        emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(this, rootView, emojiconEditText, emojiImageView);
        emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
        emojIcon.setIconsIds(R.drawable.ic_action_keyboard, R.drawable.smiley);

        emojIcon.setKeyboardListener(new EmojIconActions.KeyboardListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyboardOpen() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Keyboard opened!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyboardClose() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Keyboard closed");
            }
        });


        buttonChoose = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        buttonUpload = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_desc);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.posting_imageview_display);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        Toast.makeText(Posts_DATA.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(Posts_DATA.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String




                    String image = getStringImage(bitmap);


                //Getting Image Name
                String name = emojiconEditText.getText().toString().trim();

                byte[] data = new byte[0];
                try {
                    data = emojiconEditText.getText().toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                name = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 300, true);
                    imageView.setMaxWidth(200);
                    imageView.setMaxHeight(300);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }

        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadImage();

        }
    }

}
```

**LOGIN JAVA CLASS:**

```
public class NewLogin  extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText editTextUserName;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

String username;
String password;
String result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
}

public void invokeLogin(View view) {
    new loginAccess().execute();
}


class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    String access;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewLogin.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        String url = "";
        JSONObject json = null;

        int successValue = 0;
        try {


            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
            Log.d("TESS :: ", json.toString());
            successValue = json.getInt("success");
            //Log.d("Success Response :: ", String.valueOf(successValue));


        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return String.valueOf(successValue);
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonstring) {
        pDialog.dismiss();


        if(jsonstring.equals("1")){
            Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, Sample.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


    }
}
  }
```